# Vs Code Not Loading Jupyter Notebook Images

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I love the way vs code works with jupyter notebooks and WSL 2. However, the only thing stopping me from switching completely is the lack of image rendering from a distributed notebook. When I download a notebook from class, there are sometimes important images displaying flowcharts, diagrams, etc and these do not load on vs code but they do on Anaconda using jupyter notebook there. Any ideas?

Vs Code Jupyter Notebook

[image: Vs Code Jupyter Notebook]

anaconda jupyter notebook loaded

[image: anaconda jupyter notebook loaded]

Comment: Hi, I believe adding a code example in text mode will be more useful to anyone looking to your question. Please refer to [how to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines in order to improve your question. Thanks!

Comment: why would a code example help?